# Crashing, freezing, hanging on "Remove Stuck Pageflip"

Tags: 16.04, crash, macbook-pro, gpu-driver

My Macbook Pro is crashing, freezing, and hanging due to a bug reported as "remove stuck pageflip" by syslog. I believe.

The setup:

```
Macbook Pro A5102
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Memory: 7.7GiB
Processor: Intel Core i5-5257u CPU @ 2.7GHz x 4
Graphics: Intel Iris 6100 (Broadwell GT3)
Os type: 64-bit
Disk: 37.0GB
uname -a: Linux caleb-ubuntu 4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 12 13:48:03 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
uname -r: 4.4.0-43-generic
```

The machine will freeze with screen content still visible, cursor still responsive and reacting to screen elements, but nothing clickable or able to be interacted with. I then must `ctrl+alt+f1` until entering prompt, usually takes ~2 minutes. Then I can `ctrl+alt+f7` to return to my work.

Other times, the screen will "glitch out" and I must follow the above steps, waiting a longer period of time.

Other times, the system will totally freeze, and I must force reboot.

```
Oct 19 11:13:18 caleb-ubuntu smartd[693]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 54 to 55
Oct 19 11:15:23 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1928.576209] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: resetting error on 0:b.
Oct 19 11:15:23 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1928.576223] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:b: hotplug: scanning
Oct 19 11:15:23 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1928.576226] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:b: hotplug: no switch found

Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112344] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112370] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 1033 at /build/linux-e0bh4_/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3963 intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x1e2/0x240 [i915]()
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112371] WARN_ON(wait_event_timeout(dev_priv->pending_flip_queue, !intel_crtc_has_pending_flip(crtc), 60*HZ) == 0)
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112373] Modules linked in: btrfs xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c cpuid rfcomm nvram bnep btusb btrtl btbcm joydev btintel input_leds bcm5974 bluetooth msr binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 applesmc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal input_polldev intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul brcmfmac brcmutil snd_hda_codec_cirrus cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_generic aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_hdmi gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd bdc_pci thunderbolt snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec lpc_ich intel_pch_thermal shpchp mei_me snd_hda_core mei snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi acpi_als kfifo_buf snd_seq sbs industrialio sbshc snd_seq_device snd_timer spi_pxa2xx_platform apple_bl snd soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea ahci sysfillrect uas libahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usb_storage drm fjes video
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112414] CPU: 2 PID: 1033 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 4.4.0-42-generic #62-Ubuntu
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112416] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro12,1/Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6, BIOS MBP121.88Z.0167.B16.1602111810 02/11/2016
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112417]  0000000000000286 000000004413e07b ffff88003533faa0 ffffffff813f1f83
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112419]  ffff88003533fae8 ffffffffc020eab8 ffff88003533fad8 ffffffff81081212
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112420]  ffff880264f629a8 ffff8800357b9030 ffff880264822000 ffff880264f62800
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112421] Call Trace:
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112426]  [<ffffffff813f1f83>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112428]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112430]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112432]  [<ffffffff810c3935>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112447]  [<ffffffffc01a92a2>] intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x1e2/0x240 [i915]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112449]  [<ffffffff810c3dd0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112461]  [<ffffffffc01aa521>] intel_pre_plane_update+0x111/0x140 [i915]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112473]  [<ffffffffc01aacf2>] intel_atomic_commit+0x352/0x6f0 [i915]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112488]  [<ffffffffc003cbde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112499]  [<ffffffffc003d017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112505]  [<ffffffffc0104939>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa9/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112514]  [<ffffffffc002c269>] __setplane_internal+0x169/0x250 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112524]  [<ffffffffc003b79a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112533]  [<ffffffffc0030056>] drm_mode_setplane+0x136/0x1b0 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112540]  [<ffffffffc0021752>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112549]  [<ffffffffc002ff20>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112553]  [<ffffffff8122122f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112555]  [<ffffffff8120fdd1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x21/0x30
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112557]  [<ffffffff8120d9dd>] ? vfs_write+0x15d/0x1a0
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112558]  [<ffffffff81221499>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112561]  [<ffffffff818318b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112562] ---[ end trace c2690206b3e3a010 ]---
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112563] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112580] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 1033 at /build/linux-e0bh4_/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3968 intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x233/0x240 [i915]()
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112581] Removing stuck page flip
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112581] Modules linked in: btrfs xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c cpuid rfcomm nvram bnep btusb btrtl btbcm joydev btintel input_leds bcm5974 bluetooth msr binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 applesmc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal input_polldev intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul brcmfmac brcmutil snd_hda_codec_cirrus cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_generic aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_hdmi gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd bdc_pci thunderbolt snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec lpc_ich intel_pch_thermal shpchp mei_me snd_hda_core mei snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi acpi_als kfifo_buf snd_seq sbs industrialio sbshc snd_seq_device snd_timer spi_pxa2xx_platform apple_bl snd soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea ahci sysfillrect uas libahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usb_storage drm fjes video
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112610] CPU: 2 PID: 1033 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-42-generic #62-Ubuntu
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112610] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro12,1/Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6, BIOS MBP121.88Z.0167.B16.1602111810 02/11/2016
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112611]  0000000000000086 000000004413e07b ffff88003533faa0 ffffffff813f1f83
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112613]  ffff88003533fae8 ffffffffc020eab8 ffff88003533fad8 ffffffff81081212
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112614]  ffff880264f629a8 ffff8800357b9030 ffff880264822000 ffff880264f62800
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112616] Call Trace:
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112618]  [<ffffffff813f1f83>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112620]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112622]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112624]  [<ffffffff810c3935>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112639]  [<ffffffffc01a92f3>] intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x233/0x240 [i915]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112641]  [<ffffffff810c3dd0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112657]  [<ffffffffc01aa521>] intel_pre_plane_update+0x111/0x140 [i915]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112672]  [<ffffffffc01aacf2>] intel_atomic_commit+0x352/0x6f0 [i915]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112683]  [<ffffffffc003cbde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112694]  [<ffffffffc003d017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112699]  [<ffffffffc0104939>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa9/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112707]  [<ffffffffc002c269>] __setplane_internal+0x169/0x250 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112717]  [<ffffffffc003b79a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112727]  [<ffffffffc0030056>] drm_mode_setplane+0x136/0x1b0 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112734]  [<ffffffffc0021752>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112743]  [<ffffffffc002ff20>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112745]  [<ffffffff8122122f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112746]  [<ffffffff8120fdd1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x21/0x30
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112748]  [<ffffffff8120d9dd>] ? vfs_write+0x15d/0x1a0
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112749]  [<ffffffff81221499>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112751]  [<ffffffff818318b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct 19 11:15:49 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1954.112752] ---[ end trace c2690206b3e3a011 ]---
[drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
Oct 19 11:15:56 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1961.138660] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization

Oct 19 11:16:04 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1969.019894] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: resetting error on 0:b.
Oct 19 11:16:04 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1969.019905] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:b: got unplug event for disconnected port, ignoring
```

.

```
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653528] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653555] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 1033 at /build/linux-e0bh4_/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3963 intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x1e2/0x240 [i915]()
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653556] WARN_ON(wait_event_timeout(dev_priv->pending_flip_queue, !intel_crtc_has_pending_flip(crtc), 60*HZ) == 0)
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653557] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy btrfs xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c cpuid rfcomm nvram bnep btusb btrtl btbcm joydev btintel input_leds bcm5974 bluetooth msr binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 applesmc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal input_polldev intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul brcmfmac brcmutil snd_hda_codec_cirrus cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_generic aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_hdmi gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd bdc_pci thunderbolt snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec lpc_ich intel_pch_thermal shpchp mei_me snd_hda_core mei snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi acpi_als kfifo_buf snd_seq sbs industrialio sbshc snd_seq_device snd_timer spi_pxa2xx_platform apple_bl snd soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea ahci sysfillrect uas libahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usb_storage drm fjes video
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653597] CPU: 2 PID: 1033 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-42-generic #62-Ubuntu
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653598] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro12,1/Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6, BIOS MBP121.88Z.0167.B16.1602111810 02/11/2016
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653599]  0000000000000286 000000004413e07b ffff88003533faa0 ffffffff813f1f83
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653601]  ffff88003533fae8 ffffffffc020eab8 ffff88003533fad8 ffffffff81081212
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653602]  ffff880264f629a8 ffff8800357b9030 ffff880264822000 ffff880264f62800
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653604] Call Trace:
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653608]  [<ffffffff813f1f83>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653610]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653612]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653614]  [<ffffffff810c3935>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653630]  [<ffffffffc01a92a2>] intel_crtc_wait_for_pending_flips+0x1e2/0x240 [i915]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653632]  [<ffffffff810c3dd0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653648]  [<ffffffffc01aa521>] intel_pre_plane_update+0x111/0x140 [i915]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653664]  [<ffffffffc01aacf2>] intel_atomic_commit+0x352/0x6f0 [i915]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653678]  [<ffffffffc003cbde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653689]  [<ffffffffc003d017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653696]  [<ffffffffc0104939>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa9/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653704]  [<ffffffffc002c269>] __setplane_internal+0x169/0x250 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653714]  [<ffffffffc003b79a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653723]  [<ffffffffc0030056>] drm_mode_setplane+0x136/0x1b0 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653730]  [<ffffffffc0021752>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653739]  [<ffffffffc002ff20>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653742]  [<ffffffff8122122f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653743]  [<ffffffff8120fdd1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x21/0x30
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653746]  [<ffffffff8120d9dd>] ? vfs_write+0x15d/0x1a0
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653747]  [<ffffffff81221499>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653750]  [<ffffffff818318b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct 19 11:22:48 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 2373.653751] ---[ end trace c2690206b3e3a013 ]---
```

EDIT: I have updated the intel video driver and it still hangs:

```
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.449814] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.449910] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 973 at /var/lib/dkms/i915-4.6.3-4.4.0/1/build/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3931 intel_atomic_commit+0x15c4/0x1640 [i915]()
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.449914] Removing stuck page flip
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.449917] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy nvram rfcomm bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel input_leds joydev bcm5974 bluetooth msr binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul nls_iso8859_1 aesni_intel brcmfmac aes_x86_64 applesmc lrw input_polldev gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic brcmutil cfg80211 snd_seq_midi snd_hda_intel snd_seq_midi_event intel_pch_thermal snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_rawmidi snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_seq thunderbolt mei_me bdc_pci snd_pcm mei snd_seq_device shpchp snd_timer snd soundcore sbs acpi_als sbshc kfifo_buf industrialio mac_hid spi_pxa2xx_platform apple_bl parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid i915(OE) i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper(OE) syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ahci fb_sys_fops libahci drm video fjes uas usb_storage
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450030] CPU: 1 PID: 973 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G           OE   4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450034] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro12,1/Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6, BIOS MBP121.88Z.0167.B16.1602111810 02/11/2016
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450038]  0000000000000086 00000000bb9a1ca9 ffff880070623af8 ffffffff813f1f93
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450044]  ffff880070623b40 ffffffffc02150d0 ffff880070623b30 ffffffff81081212
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450050]  0000000000000000 ffff880264fcb9a8 0000000000000000 ffff88025fa9f000
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450056] Call Trace:
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450068]  [<ffffffff813f1f93>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450077]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450082]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450091]  [<ffffffff810c3935>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450152]  [<ffffffffc019f714>] intel_atomic_commit+0x15c4/0x1640 [i915]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450160]  [<ffffffff810c3dd0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450215]  [<ffffffffc006fbde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450255]  [<ffffffffc0070017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450284]  [<ffffffffc00fb8c9>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa9/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450317]  [<ffffffffc005f269>] __setplane_internal+0x169/0x250 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450356]  [<ffffffffc006e79a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450392]  [<ffffffffc0063056>] drm_mode_setplane+0x136/0x1b0 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450419]  [<ffffffffc0054752>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450453]  [<ffffffffc0062f20>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450463]  [<ffffffff8122123f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450469]  [<ffffffff8120fde1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x21/0x30
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450476]  [<ffffffff8120d9ed>] ? vfs_write+0x15d/0x1a0
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450481]  [<ffffffff812214a9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450489]  [<ffffffff818318b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct 19 14:24:51 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 1189.450493] ---[ end trace 633a0aa7b384f0dd ]---
```

.

```
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454419] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454447] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 1070 at /var/lib/dkms/i915-4.6.3-4.4.0/1/build/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3931 intel_atomic_commit+0x15c4/0x1640 [i915]()
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454448] Removing stuck page flip
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454449] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy nvram rfcomm msr bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth input_leds joydev bcm5974 snd_hda_codec_hdmi binfmt_misc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass nls_iso8859_1 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_cirrus applesmc snd_hda_codec_generic input_polldev aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm lpc_ich snd_seq_midi intel_pch_thermal snd_seq_midi_event brcmfmac snd_rawmidi brcmutil cfg80211 snd_seq thunderbolt snd_seq_device bdc_pci snd_timer mei_me snd shpchp mei soundcore sbs sbshc acpi_als kfifo_buf apple_bl industrialio spi_pxa2xx_platform mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_apple hid_generic usbhid hid uas i915(OE) i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper(OE) syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci usb_storage fjes video
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454485] CPU: 2 PID: 1070 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W  OE   4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454486] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro12,1/Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6, BIOS MBP121.88Z.0167.B16.1602111810 02/11/2016
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454487]  0000000000000086 0000000041bba34a ffff8802613bfaf8 ffffffff813f1f93
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454489]  ffff8802613bfb40 ffffffffc02130d0 ffff8802613bfb30 ffffffff81081212
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454490]  0000000000000000 ffff8800355631a8 0000000000000000 ffff8800357e8000
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454492] Call Trace:
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454496]  [<ffffffff813f1f93>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454498]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454500]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454502]  [<ffffffff810c3935>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454517]  [<ffffffffc019d714>] intel_atomic_commit+0x15c4/0x1640 [i915]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454519]  [<ffffffff810c3dd0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454533]  [<ffffffffc0058bde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454541]  [<ffffffffc0059017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454549]  [<ffffffffc00f98c9>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa9/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454557]  [<ffffffffc0048269>] __setplane_internal+0x169/0x250 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454566]  [<ffffffffc005779a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454575]  [<ffffffffc004c056>] drm_mode_setplane+0x136/0x1b0 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454581]  [<ffffffffc003d752>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454588]  [<ffffffffc004bf20>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454592]  [<ffffffff8122123f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454593]  [<ffffffff8120fde1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x21/0x30
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454595]  [<ffffffff8120d9ed>] ? vfs_write+0x15d/0x1a0
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454596]  [<ffffffff812214a9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454599]  [<ffffffff818318b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct 20 10:52:33 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [ 3691.454600] ---[ end trace 3f5153c0fc8dac98 ]---
```

Edit: Per comments below, attempted entering `intel-pstate=disable` into the grub boot menu. A crash followed later despite this.

```
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745900] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745925] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 1010 at /var/lib/dkms/i915-4.6.3-4.4.0/1/build/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:3931 intel_atomic_commit+0x15c4/0x1640 [i915]()
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745926] Removing stuck page flip
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745926] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy nvram rfcomm bnep msr btusb btrtl btbcm joydev btintel bluetooth input_leds bcm5974 snd_hda_codec_hdmi binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel applesmc input_polldev kvm irqbypass snd_hda_codec_cirrus crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec_generic crc32_pclmul aesni_intel snd_hda_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper snd_hda_core cryptd snd_hwdep snd_pcm brcmfmac intel_pch_thermal snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi brcmutil thunderbolt cfg80211 snd_seq lpc_ich snd_seq_device snd_timer mei_me bdc_pci mei snd shpchp soundcore sbs sbshc mac_hid acpi_als apple_bl kfifo_buf industrialio spi_pxa2xx_platform parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic hid_apple usbhid hid uas usb_storage i915(OE) i2c_algo_bit ahci drm_kms_helper(OE) syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt libahci fb_sys_fops drm video fjes
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745963] CPU: 3 PID: 1010 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G           OE   4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745964] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro12,1/Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6, BIOS MBP121.88Z.0167.B16.1602111810 02/11/2016
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745965]  0000000000000086 000000002bc2e3b3 ffff880263dfbaf8 ffffffff813f1f93
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745967]  ffff880263dfbb40 ffffffffc01f60d0 ffff880263dfbb30 ffffffff81081212
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745968]  0000000000000000 ffff880264f641a8 0000000000000000 ffff880264822000
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745970] Call Trace:
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745974]  [<ffffffff813f1f93>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745977]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745978]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745981]  [<ffffffff810c3935>] ? finish_wait+0x55/0x70
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745994]  [<ffffffffc0180714>] intel_atomic_commit+0x15c4/0x1640 [i915]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.745996]  [<ffffffff810c3dd0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746008]  [<ffffffffc0048bde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746016]  [<ffffffffc0049017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746022]  [<ffffffffc00cd8c9>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xa9/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746030]  [<ffffffffc0038269>] __setplane_internal+0x169/0x250 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746038]  [<ffffffffc004779a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746046]  [<ffffffffc003c056>] drm_mode_setplane+0x136/0x1b0 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746052]  [<ffffffffc002d752>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746059]  [<ffffffffc003bf20>] ? drm_plane_check_pixel_format+0x50/0x50 [drm]
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746062]  [<ffffffff8122123f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746063]  [<ffffffff8120fde1>] ? __sb_end_write+0x21/0x30
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746065]  [<ffffffff8120d9ed>] ? vfs_write+0x15d/0x1a0
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746067]  [<ffffffff812214a9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746069]  [<ffffffff818318b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct 24 10:01:50 caleb-ubuntu kernel: [  670.746070] ---[ end trace a7505d5c06aeffea ]---
```

Comment: Is your MacBook getting hot? What type of connection on the second monitor? Also I'd leave a terminal open running the command top on the second monitor and see if anything spikes when it freezes.

Comment: I will monitor heat, though I didn't specifically notice that previously. Is there a way to be logging "top" somehow?  The event is so rare I'd have to have the terminal open on every desktop, which would be a bit annoying as I am constantly flipping around desktops and am a bit of a screen real estate nazi :P

Comment: you could try updated intel driver. may be they fixed what seems to be a bug. https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads or you can try that PPA https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers with also updated intel driver. Chooose one not both.

Comment: @solsTiCe That was a good idea but unfortunately it just hung again after updating the driver. Lots of things are rendering a lot better now, so good tip either way!

Comment: This issue has been being tracked for some time, although I see no clear solution https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1413238  https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89519 note that this question is now number 3 on google search results despite numerous other results.

Comment: Here's the most up to date discussion I've found: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1195870

Comment: Hah, it's a kernel bug being reported by fedora, gentoo, arch linux users... https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1007522-start-0-postdays-0-postorder-asc-highlight-.html?sid=d3eb60fa12c717debf91cf0550e2d7ee https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195844

Comment: @komali_2 Have you tried disabling intel_pstate? I used to have a similar problem upon logging in. Add intel_pstate=disable into the Grub commands at boot and see what happens.

Comment: @PatrickNegus I'm googling around how to enter grub commands at boot and the answers are so varied I'm afraid I'll do this in the wrong spot. Can you clarify how to best enter Grub commands at boot?

Comment: Ok. So, when you boot into Grub, press "e". Right after the words *quiet splash*, add *intel_pstate=disable*. What you enter will not be retained after that boot, so we can see if this works.

Comment: I just tried it before seeing your comment, there was an option "press c to enter command prompt" which I used.  Was that the wrong spot then? Cheers for clarifying. EDIT: I can see that it was. One sec, rebooting again.

Comment: I have entered the command at the bottom of whatever file pressing "e" opens in that nano-esque editor. Will test today and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Unfortunately, this seemed to not fix it. What sort of machine were you on when you were having similar problems? I almost feel like this is primarily being caused by a monitor being plugged into the displayport.

Comment: @komali_2 After some research, it looks like this is a bug with Intel Iris drivers crashing when trying to drive resolutions higher than 900p. Try lowering the resolution and see what happens, if you can. Have you tried updating your kernel?

Comment: @PatrickNegus where'd you turn up that research? Would love to read into it more as well. Current rez is EDIT: "2160p = 3840 x 2160 - commonly known as 4K." Will attempt lowering resolution. Kernel information added to OP, will test resolution fix, followed by updated kernel. If one or both work, will illustrate as such so you can add the answer with one/both solutions.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Neither lowering the resolution nor updating ubuntu or the kernel has solved the problem. I've issued a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1636327

Comment: Same issue here. I am running 16.04 with a Dell XPS 13 9350.

Comment: I added to  my grub options:
intel_idle.max_cstate=1
If it works for you you can add it to /etc/default/grub, in the line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

I still getting the error but it is not flickering nor freezing by now (but I still seeing the error). If it works for you let me know so get can get "closer" to a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

I added to my grub options: `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` If it works for you you can add it to `/etc/default/grub`, in the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"` I still getting the error but it is not flickering nor freezing by now (but I still seeing the error). If it works for you let me know so get can get "closer" to a workaround (as I commented).

Let's see if it works!

Comment: For others - make sure to edit grub with `sudo` such like `sudo gedit grub` so your changes save.

Comment: This is the closest we're going to get and the bounty expires in an hour. Great link! I hadn't thought to check the kernel bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks! But anyway, keep me posted and let's see if we keep having errors. Together we might find faster and better workarounds or fixes than on our own. If you experience a new freeze or any other related thingie, just let me know and we'll try to figure out what to do

Comment: I still having eventual glitches but I stop seeing the error messages. Will see how it evolves...

Comment: I've no glitches yet, nor crashes. I'm keeping a weather eye out. Later today I'll try upping the resolution on the external monitor to see if I can force a crash. From the thread you posted, it looks as if doing cstate or pstate to 2 instead of 1 might be something worth trying. I need to read more into what the settings control exactly, seems like something about power usage.

Comment: oof, just had another

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel gets into a High load problem like running an endless loop of creating random Mac address's or some other process.

I have seen the Top average load indicator go/driven as high as 80-85 then the system kernel goes into some sort of recovery mode Blanking the screen.

I think its called the "Bash infinite Loop of death".

Log the Top command to a TXT file top >> top.txt then you may find a bit more info out, the log output is not really that good formatted maybe someone else could Help with that.

As a precaution I would change all of you passwords just in case do it disconnected from any network.

Comment: 2nd for anybody that knows a cleaner way to log this, the output is horrifying