# After crash I'm unable to arrange combined displays and trackpad settings are not visible

Tags: gnome, touchpad, 16.10

I upgraded to 16.10 a few days ago and had a total freeze on the system; unresponsive cursor, couldn't exit X and had to force shutdown vi the power button. After that I have been experiencing problems with a dual display setup which don't allow arranging them. Instead the system logs out.

Furthermore the touchpad settings are not visible any longer and I cannot change the scrolling method to natural scrolling. The dconf editor (under org> gnome> desktop> peripherals> touchpad) states that the natural-scroll setting is enabled though. The scenario is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783396/mouse-touchpad-separate-settings-missing). I've got  `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` installed instead of `libinput`.

Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 running on a 13" MacBook 5,1 (2009)

Comment: ot both the touchpad and dual screen problem solved by reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, uninstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and rebooting. So the opposite to the [answer in the post](http://askubuntu.com/a/783734/328311) which I linked to.

The problem persists though with the keyboard and trackpad stop responding after ~hour. Driver problem? The bcm5974 entry which was previously in the xinput list is not present any longer.

Comment: Added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"` as described in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/842850/328311). Still a problem with keyboard/trackpad crashes though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem being that both libinput and the synaptics drivers were present. I've deleted synaptics driver as it's legacy and got libinput instead:

`sudo apt install libinput-bin & xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

which leaves me with quite an empty mouse/trackpad pane in system settings. The only options there are the choices of either using the left or right button for the primary click.

Current mouse/trackpad settings can be set with `gpointing-device-settings` or in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-libinput.conf`.

[image: gpointing device settings]

As for the problem with the display, a reinstall of the nVidia driver

`sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-340`

and a reboot made the screens work together again.

Comment: Reacted too early. After a kernal update `libinput` got installed again and the keyboard and mouse froze. I uninstalled `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` but ended up with a jumping cursor. Now I've reinstalled synaptics and `touchpad indicator`. The later is the only settings which enables natural scrolling.  Let's see how long this configuration will last before a kb/tp freeze.

Comment: Got a crash on the keyboard/trackpad and found an error log at /var/crash/_opt_extras.ubuntu.com_touchpad-indicator_bin_touchpad-indicator.1000.crash    
`ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 4.8.0-28.30-generic 4.8.6
SourcePackage: touchpad-indicator
Tags: yakkety third-party-packages
Title: touchpad-indicator crashed with OSError in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/share/touchpad-indicator/comun.py: [Errno 5] Inp$
Uname: Linux 4.8.0-28-generic x86_64
UnreportableReason: This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.`
will try without this

Comment: Seemingly libinput is taking precedence over the synaptics driver in terms of development. I've switched over to libinput which at first left me with a cursor which mapped to the absolute position of the cursor to the screen. This meant that when, for instance, touching the top right corner of the touch pad the cursor would jump there. Finally I got found that one has to install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` to get the touch pad to function normally. This could have maybe been installed by default...

Comment: Keyboard and trackpad still freeze even when xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package is uninstalled. Any help of which log files to look for debug information would be appreciated.